# What song plays from 7:20 to 8:05 of FMA Brotherhood episode 5?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

Does anybody know the name of the song that plays at `7:20` - `8:05` on Brotherhood episode 5, or the OST it's on?

Comment: Can you describe what happens during the scene? There's no soundtrack playing at the specified time duration in the episode I have downloaded. The closest one is at 9:20 when Ed and Alphonse are talking, and it begins when Ed says "I'm an idiot" and plays until Scar attacks Ed. Is that the one you're referring to?

Comment: Have you tried [Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood OST - Nightfall in Central City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1VBeQlmJJA&list=PLE36689FDB43CE335)?

Comment: @Pratyush Manocha I have tried Nightfall in Central City, it's not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @Ashish Gupta Yes, I'm referring exactly to the scene you mentioned! That's the one!

Comment: @KatarzynaNowakowska I thought you were referring to the one at 4. In any case, I had sent you a playlist with all the OSTs, try going through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The soundtrack you're looking for is [Trisha's Lullaby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2kwie-gs2o) from [Fullmetal Alchemist Original Soundtrack 1 album](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist_Brotherhood_Original_Soundtrack_1).

[image]

It's the 21st soundtrack in the album with a time duration of 3 minutes and 31 seconds.